# Parallelize a for loop using multi-threading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a for loop in java with the following structure that I need to parallelize into a fixed number of threads. Lets say that number is in `numThreads`. The for loop is given below. Note that only the outer loop needs to be parallelized. I think I need to use Executor but I can't figure out how to split the workload into different threads, and if that will change my indexes inside the loop in statements like `isInsulator[x][y]`. basically I want different threads splitting the value of X and running a for loop for those x values assigned to them. Does that make sense? Can anyone help me achieve this or maybe push me in the right direction please?

Comment: Unrelated: dont use empty lines just because you can. You use vertical spacing to **group** things somehow. Just having empty lines all over the place doesnt help your human readers. To the contrary. Empty lines are fine, but as non-empty lines, you use them because it makes sense, not because you can!

Comment: are the arrays (isInsulator, isHeater, nextArr and currArr) class variable or local variable?

Comment: Can you tell a bit more on the method giveHeat do ? Is it thread safe ?

Comment: Does `giveHeat()` make use of the results from the previous iteration? (I suspect it might do as you are passing `x - 1`.) If so, then you can't use parallel processing.

Comment: The arrays isInsulator, isHeater, nextArr and currArr are class variables. 
giveHeat() is not thread safe. However, I'm not worried about that at the moment. 
I will be changing the call to avoid race condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a fixed thread pool (it will initialize and use only the specified number of threads):

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
```

You have to submit X tasks to the thread pool:

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
        final int x = i;
        executor.execute(() -> submitTask(x));
}
```

In the method submitTask you can define your logic:

```
private void submitTask(final int x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < Y; y++) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a benchmark (so you can prove it's really faster with parallel processing), use JMH.
2. Rewrite the code to be a `produce_inputs->process->collect_or_summarize` pipeline
3. Use parallel `Stream`s API (it uses an internal fork-join pool tuned to the number of CPUs on the box).
4. Compare the performance of sequential vs paralle processing.

```
int result = IntStream.generate(() -> 42) // lazy inputs source
        .limit(100) // limit number of inputs
        .parallel() // use parallel processing
//      .sequential() // ...or sequential processing
        .map(x -> x + 1) // do the processing
        .reduce(0, Math::addExact); // summarize the result
//      .collect(toList()); // ...or just collect it to a container
```